# iCloud/Google calendar sync issues on OS X 10.9.1

Tags: macbook-pro, calendar, ical, macos

I have recently upgraded to Mavericks, 10.9.1. I am trying to share my diary with my wife, we both use the OS X Calendar and I decided to sync using iCloud.

I also have calendars in Calendar synced through Google.

I went into `System Preferences > iCloud` and ticked `Calendars`. It told me it would merge all my calendars data in Calendars on My Mac to the Calendars in iCloud which is what I wanted.

I said OK, it then whirred away for about three minutes and then all my calendars on My Mac disappeared and were replaced by iCloud calendars, a bit more whirring and then I saw an error saying it couldn't access iCloud at this time, try again now or try later, I tried now several times and later as well all to no avail.

Getting desperate I went into `System Preferences > iCloud` and un-ticked `Calendars`. It told me all Calendar data would be deleted on my mac which I was not concerned about as I was well backed up.

All iCloud Calendars disappeared from the side pane leaving only the Google calendars left.

This is my challenge: I can't create a Calendar on My Mac. When I go to `File > New Calendar`, there is no option to create on on My Mac which was there before, in fact no option to create anything.

I have tried the usual computer reboot and logging out of iCloud to no avail.

I have logged onto iCloud and some of my Calendars are there but at this point I would be happy just to be able to get back to square one with my Calendars re-created on My Mac.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create events without a calendar to put them in, and you can't create calendars without an account. Since you have no available cloud service, you need to create the calendars in the On My Mac account.

1. Completely log out and remove all accounts that could store calendars, including iCloud and Google.
2. Open Calendars → Preferences → Accounts (Not Calendars → Accounts).
3. Select the On My Mac account and check the Enable this account box.

Comment: Cant find a place to say thanks for taking the time to answer this, easy when you know how;)  Anyway, thanks grgarside

Comment: @FredG No problem! Welcome to Ask Different!